# Unable to unset session variable. It's getting regenerated on page refresh

Tags: php, wordpress, session-variables

i am using a session variable to store flash messages and once the message is displayed out i want to unset the session variable since i don't want to display the same message if the request is not coming from a scrip that processed a form submit.

This is what i am doing.

1. Submitting a form
2. Processing the request and setting the session variables.

```php
session_start();
$_SESSION['custom_flash_message'] = json_encode( array(
    'class'     => 'success',
    'message'   => 'Changes Saved Successfully !'
) );
```

3. Redirecting the user back to the form.(**Actually i am using WordPress and these things are taking place inside a WordPress Dashboard**)

```php
wp_redirect( wp_get_referer() );
exit;
```

4. On the Page i am checking if such a session variable exists and displays the message

```php
if ( isset( $_SESSION['custom_flash_message'] ) ) {
    echo "<pre>", $_SESSION['custom_flash_message'], "</pre>";
    $flash = json_decode( $_SESSION['custom_flash_message'], true );
    ?>
    <div class="notice notice-<?php echo $flash['class'];?>">
    <p><?php echo $flash['message']; ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
    $_SESSION['custom_flash_message'] = '';
    unset( $_SESSION['custom_flash_message'] );
    echo "<pre>", $_SESSION['custom_flash_message'], "</pre>";
}
```

As you can see i have echoed out the session variable before & after unsetting the variable and this is what i am getting,

**Before :**

```json
{"class":"success","message":"Changes Saved Successfully !"}
```

**After :**
`Notice:  Undefined index: icon_trailer_flash in /home/nginx/domains/path...`

This is the desired result. But even when i refresh the page i am getting the same result. It is echoing out the session variable in the first case and error in the second case.

Since i am un-setting the session variable after displaying, how it is getting displayed the next time. How the execution is entering the first if statement. I have no idea, i'm getting crazy about this.

Do you guys have any idea on how to solve this ? And why such a weird thing happens ?

**EDIT - MY ACTUAL SESSION HELPER CLASS**

```php
<?php

class Custom_Flash_Helper
{
    const FLASH_KEY = 'custom_flash';

    public function __construct()
    {
        if ( session_id() == '' || ! isset( $_SESSION ) ) {
            session_start();
        }
    }

    public static function set_flash( string $class, string $message ): void
    {
        $_SESSION[self::FLASH_KEY] = json_encode( array(
            'class'     => $class,
            'message'   => $message
        ) );
    }

    public static function unset_flash(): void
    {
        if ( isset( $_SESSION[self::FLASH_KEY] ) ) {
            $_SESSION[self::FLASH_KEY] = '';
            unset( $_SESSION[self::FLASH_KEY] );
        }
    }

    public static function print(): void
    {
        if ( isset( $_SESSION[self::FLASH_KEY] ) ) {
            $flash = json_decode( $_SESSION[self::FLASH_KEY], true );
            $class = $flash['class'];
            ?>
            <div class="notice notice-<?php echo $class?>">
                <p><?php echo $flash['message']; ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php
            self::unset_flash();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is what i am doing i the front-end to display the session data,

```
<diV>
    <h1>Manage Dealer</h1>
    <?php Custom_Flash_Helper::print(); ?>
    <!-- OTHER STUFF -->
</div>
```

Comment: _“How the execution is entering the first if statement.”_ - have you checked what the whole session contains _before_ your if statement …? Maybe your “form processing” code actually executes more than once?

Comment: @CBroe , No it doesn't i have checked by adding an ```exit``` call and it only getting executed at the time of submitting the form. And i am processing the form only if ```$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'``` Since Refreshing the page doesn't bypass this check, i don't think that the code that sets the session will be executed twice.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are refreshing the Form page submit.

It is working like this:

1. Form page: Submits to another page (Post page).
2. Post page: `$_SESSION['custom_flash_message']` is created. `wp_redirect` redirects us back to the Form page.
3. Form page: Shows and destroys `$_SESSION['custom_flash_message']` .

All good so far.
But when you "refresh" the page you are not actually refreshing the Form page.
You are refreshing the Post page.
The wp_redirect just makes it look like you are refreshing the Form page.
So you are actually refreshing back to step 2 and recreating the `$_SESSION['custom_flash_message']` .
Try just clicking on the URL in the browser location bar and hit enter.
This will reload the Form page, but without a redirect.
You will see the `$_SESSION['custom_flash_message']` was destroyed.

You can stop this by adding a unique id in the form and testing for it on the Post page.

Add a hidden element in your Form page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="formId" value = "<?php echo uniqid(); ?>">
```

This $_POST['formId'] will be unique every time the form is submitted.

Then change your creation code to:

```
If ( $_POST['formId'] != $_SESSION['formId'] ) {
    $_SESSION['custom_flash_message'] = json_encode( array(
        'class'     => 'success',
        'message'   => 'Changes Saved Successfully !'
    ) );
    $_SESSION['formId'] = $_POST['formId'];
}
```

Now the Post page will only create the message from a fresh form.
If you refresh the page it sends the same formId and the message is not created.

Comment: Sorry for the super late reply. I was a bit busy with some other projects. The unique id may solve the problem, but the thing that concerns me is why the session unset isn't working. You are right, when we refresh the page it may be re-creating the session. But when i hit the URL in the browser address bar for multiple times or come back to the page after visiting another page it is getting displayed there, all the time.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the session helper class logic.